# Implement a form in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am currently the Salesforce administrator of a company Enterprise account. Our accounts are made up of universities. I was asked to implement a form for trips.

The trips basic information is: Trip name, University, Region, Country, Project manager and Project manager met. I created the object trip and added the custom fields using lookup relationships with contacts and accounts. This was very easy to do so.

The first problem is as we move through the form. The next section is about the university info which has these fields: Number of students, Number of faculty, Language. They are asking me that these fields override the information that was previously stored in the account. Like if you pick X university and it had 200 students originally, then if I write 205 in the field , it will overwrite the previously set number.

My second problem is, in the next section of the form they have an objectives section.
For example, there is a text field with the label :

"Objective 1 ***_*__*_*__*_*____**" +

if you want to add a new objective there is a "+" sign that will create a new field

"Objective 1 ***_*__*_*__*_*____**" +

"Objective 2 ***_*__*_*__*_*____**"

How can I achieve this? Is there a way with basic creating system? Do I need to create a Visualforce page? Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's a version of stackexchange specifically for salesforce: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/. You can likely find better advice there

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand of your 1st problem: On the trip object you have a lookup to account (university) and there are number of students etc field on the trip object and whenever a user updates it here it should be update back in the Account Object?

Instead of doing this, as you're already capturing all this data in the account object, use formula fields in the trip object to populate the data. This i think would be a better data model. But if you still wish to do it the way you intend to then you will have to write a trigger on trip object and update the account with that information. The problem with the second option would be: lets say you create a trip 1 record and update the #of students to 210, and this would be updated in the account as 210. And then you create a trip2 record for the same account and here you input the value of the #of Students field to 230, so the account(university) record with the value 230. But the problem is the value in trip 1 record will still remain 210. I hope you understand what I am trying to explain.

Coming to the 2nd Problem:

Here too the data model will be slightly different:
Create another object called Objective which has a master detail relationship with the trip object. So the Objective will be a related list in the trip object. For every trip there will be a number of objective which you can add in the related list. This is quite simple and there would be no need of any coding. But if you want to add the + sign which would display another field when the user clicked on it: In this case too the data model is the same, but you would need to create a VF page(which could either in-line VF page or a entirely an independent VF page) and then whenever a user clicks the + sign a new field is shown.